# CSS media query headache

Tags: ios, css, iphone

as I've said before: ** Amateur Warning **

I'm having trouble with my media queries for iphone (on portrait orientation).

Here are my queries:

For Large monitors

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 861px)
```

For not so large monitors

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-height:860px)
```

For ipads and when windows are small

```
@media only screen and (min-width:760px) and (max-width:1023px), screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)
```

For iphones (3 and up)

```
@media screen and (max-width:759px) and (orientation: portrait), screen and (max-device-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait)
```

My iphone (on landscape orientation) triggers the ipad and small windows query... any suggestions?

I want the iphone on landscape orientation to trigger the "ipad" css but when on portrait to trigger the iphone css.

AND - just on a final note, it displays well (as it should) when I shrink my browser window on my mac, the problem is w the iphone - i've tried on an iphone 5 and a 3S

Comment: Have you looked at this [site](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)?

Comment: if u mean stackoverflow, yes, quite...

Comment: Let me make myself more clearer than the hyperlink on my first comment.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: ha! yeh... explicit helps sometimes... and yes, as suggested in that site, i replaced my iphone media query and joggled with my ipad and iphone queries and still no luck - What i'd like to know is why is my ipad query triggering on my iphone - why are my parameters wrong

Comment: On your iPhone query, I noticed that you are missing an `only` keyword between `@media` and `screen`. Did you check for that in your actual code?

Comment: Added it, no change...

Comment: Would you mind making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can manipulate what you have worked on so far?

Answer (score 0):

use this code for IPhone 5 media queries:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px)
```

If you want to support portrait:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
```

and for landscape:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, this is working for me:

1 - Add this tag to your html head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

2 - Add this media query for iPhone Portrait:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {}
```

3 - Add this media query for iPad and iPhone Landscape:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The magic number was 568px - this is the threshhold where seemingly, iphones have their max-device-width, no matter if it's an iphone 3 you are working with.

So what was happening is that my threshold was at 768...

These are my final queries for iphone portrait:

```
screen  and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation:portrait)
```

For the rest what i showed earlier within these parameters:

```
screen  and (min-device-width : 569px), (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation:landscape)
```